# Web Scraping Encountered XML Parsing Error, How to Fix?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, python-requests, xml.etree

I've been using a web-scraping application for a year or so now with no real issues. This morning, I ran the program and got a mismatched tag error from xml.etree. This has never happened before this morning, so I am a little a stumped as to why all of a sudden it's happening now. Here's my code:

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import json
import datetime as dt
import time
from dateutil import parser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xml.parsers import expat


url = 'https://www5.fdic.gov/cra/WebServices/DBService.asmx/callWS'

r = requests.post(url, data={"functionName":"SearchCRA","parmsJSON":"{\"Appl_Number\":\"\",\"Appl_Type\":\"\",\"PSTALP\":\"\",\"SUPRV_FDICDBS\":\"09\",\"BANK_NAME\":\"\"}"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

root = ET.fromstring(r.content)
data = json.loads(root.text)

today = dt.date.today()
lastweek = today-dt.timedelta(7)
date = lastweek.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") #one week from today in mm/d/yyyy

mylist = []
for result in data['Result']:
    d = parser.parse(result['Appl_Recd_YMD'])
    f_d = d.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

    if f_d >= date:
        new_status = "***NEW***"
    else:
        new_status = "        "

if 'INTERIM' not in result['Instname'] and result['Inst_Rle_Cde'] == '1' and result['Appl_Type'] in ('REORG ', 'MERGER', 'RELMO', 'FDINEW'):
    output4 = 'Date: {} Application Number: {} Institution: {} State: {} Type: {} Link: https://www5.fdic.gov/cra/cram03.aspx?inApplNb={}&inApplType={} {}'.format(f_d, result['Appl_Number'], result['Instname'].strip(),result['Pstalp'], result['Appl_Type'],result['Appl_Number'], result['Appl_Type'], new_status)
    item = output4
    mylist.append(item)
    slist = sorted(mylist)
    print(len(mylist), end=""),
    print('.)', end = ""),
    print(output4)
    global slist2
    slist2 = slist
```

And here's the error I get:

```
  File "C:/Users/d1rjr03/PycharmProjects/Discovery/FDIC.py", line 16, in <module>
root = ET.fromstring(r.content)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1315, in XML
parser.feed(text)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 7, column 2
```

This error makes me wonder if its an issue with the website or maybe just my access?

I don't have a ton of experience with xml.etree so I am not quite sure where to start in terms of remedying the situation. Any idea why this is happening all of a sudden?

Comment: `r.content` is not well-formed XML. For example, there is no `</BR>` end tag and there are unquoted attribute values (`TYPE=HIDDEN`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the request url changed from 'www5' to 'www7'. Super simple answer, frankly, I should've found it before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the value of r.content before passing it into ET.fromstring, is it what you are expecting? Either print it to screen, write it to a log file or run the code with a debugger and check the value. From the error it suggests that the value will not be what you think it is

Comment: Interesting, I get the following error (it's too long to post here) but it includes: The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.